# wrap elements already created (after, before, etc.)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've already created my divs in Jquery, but i would like to wrap them all in a div, to work with slideToggle. But i don't see how i can do that, could you please help me?

here's my code :

```
var $container = $('...(bug)div class="container">')    
                .hide()    
                .appendTo($monid)    
                .fadeIn('slow')    
                .before('..(bug)div class="up">')    
                .after('..(bug)div class="down">');
```

and i would like to wrap the divs : "up, down, container" to a new div. Do you have any solution?

Thanks

Comment: is that the actual code?  You have '(bug)' in it?

Comment: @Keoki Zee : Thanks, i'll do it from now. Why do i get a -1 on my question?

Comment: @FiveTools : no actually the code did not show up on the preview, so i added this little "bug" to say it was a bug on the message.

Comment: @Paul I wasn't the person who downvoted you, so I don't know...

Comment: @Keoki Zee : ok no prob, thanks for the tip anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wrapall.

http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/

Something like this:

`$(".up, .down, .container").wrapAll("<div/>")`

Comment: Thanks kingjiv for the quick answer

Answer (score 0):

var $container = $('div.container')
                .hide()
                .appendTo($monid)
                .fadeIn('slow')
                .before('div.up')
                .after('div.down');